# Where is my jQuery error? Combing AJAX with a dropdown

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am currently running the following AJAX function from a button with a class named '.decline'

```
$(function() {
    $(".decline").click(function(){

        var element = $(this);
        var del_id = element.attr("id1");
        var order_id = element.attr("data-order1");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "decline.php",
            //data: info,
            data: {id1:del_id,order_id1:order_id},
            success: function(){cache: false}
        });

        $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    });
});
```

This works as needed, but now I have added a dropdown to my button like this:

```
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-tip">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="decline" href="#1" id1="<?php echo $id1; ?>" data-order1="<?php echo $name; ?>">Item One </a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Item Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Item three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and Ive changed the AJAX as follows (just the class that executes it)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    $(".decline a").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var del_id = element.attr("id1");
        var order_id = element.attr("data-order1");

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "decline.php",
           //data: info,
           data: {id1:del_id,order_id1:order_id},
           success: function(){cache: false}
        });

        $(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow").animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
    });
});

</script>
```

My dropdown works as needed, but now I can no longer run my AJAX function. Id suspect its an issue with the class Ive assigned in the jQuery, but I cant track it down.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, you should use `a.decline` instead of `.decline a` as a selector. I cannot comprehend what you intend to achieve with `success: function(){cache: false}`, though.

Comment: The change didnt work, but thanks for your input., The empty function is a placeholder for upcoming work.

Answer (score 0):

The following looks wrong to me:

```
success: function(){cache: false}
```

Perhaps you meant to fill in a function body:

```
success: function() { ... },<br>
cache: false
```

Also I think you need to use `a.decline` to select the element you're interested in.